# Django order by calculated value

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have 2 models,

```
Player
- id: int
- name: string

Ball
- type: string
- player_id: int
```

Basically the idea is that a player can posses certain number of balls. The type of the ball can be BIG or SMALL (stored as string value) in ball.type

Now I would like to sort the players based on a calculated reputation. The formula for reputation is as follows

`reputation = No of Big balls x 10 + No of Small balls`

So for e.g. the reputation of a player with one big and one small ball would be 11.

Could someone give an idea on how to order users based on this reputation? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can try annotating and using that to order:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q, Value

Player.objects.all().annotate(reputation=Count('ball', filter=Q(ball__type="BIG")) * Value(10) + Count('ball', filter=Q(ball__type="SMALL"))).order_by('reputation')
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I get an idea. Actually I had my formula for reputation a bit inaccurate. How would we account for the small ball count in your above code? Thanks

Comment: @Sagar edited the answer. Also you can negate the Q object by writing `~Q(.....)` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of Django `Manager` class. Consider the code:

```
class PlayerManager(models.Manager):
    def with_reputation(self):
        # using the formula from "Abdul Aziz Barkat"
        return self.annotate(reputation = Count('ball', filter=Q(ball__type="BIG")) * Value(10) + \
                                          Count('ball', filter=Q(ball__type="SMALL")))
```

and in your Players model you use the with_reputation to generate a queryset that has the reputation annotation, that you can sort

```
class Player(models):
     objects = PlayerManager()
```

now in your code you can use Players.objects.with_reputation() to get a queryset with the annotation `reputation` added to every record. Then you can use that to do the ordering

```
Players.objects.with_reputation().order_by('reputation')
```

or:

```
Players.objects.with_reputation().filter(name='Sam').ordere_by('reputation')
```

You can read more about managers here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/

Comment: `.order_by('reputation')` can be done inside of `with_reputation`. Might make sense to do that if you're always going to want to use that sorting. Also, you needn't replace the standard `objects` `Manager` with your new one - you could always include both `objects = Manager()` and `pm = PlayerManager()` within `class Player`.